# How to reference objects in an array created with .select method?

Tags: arrays, ruby, methods

As I understand it, running a .select method on an array generates a new array. My question is how to reference that new array?

So when I have something like this:

```
Num = [3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19]
x = rand(1..10)
Num.select { |i| i > x}
```

I want to reference specific objects in the new array generated by this .select.

For example, I'd like to say

```
puts new_array[0]
```

Or something similar. But since the new array doesn't have a "name," I don't know how to call the objects in it.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `new_array = Num.select {|i| i > x}` then `new_array[0]` etc.

Comment: So obvious. Thank you.  I had tried
   `new_array = []
    new_array << Num.select { |i| i > x}`
but that added an array within an array. This is so simple. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You assign a local variable to the result of the `select`.

```
num = [3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19]
x = rand(1..10)
new_array = num.select { |i| i > x}
puts new_array[0]
```

I also changed your variable `Num` to `num`. Usually, only classes are named with the first letter capitalized and the rest lowercase.